# Checkboxes in a sub-form datasheet view in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2000

I am new to MS Access. I have a subform on which I need a checkbox on each row displayed in the subform.  My subform is in a datasheet view.

There are a number of posts on the web that talk about this but none provide a clear answer.

Can anyone help by pointing me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using the datasheet view, then the control type is determined by the data type.  So if there's a Yes/No (boolean) field in the dataset, then it should appear as a checkbox in the form.

Comment: What if my database does not have a Yes/no type column? Is there any way that I can dynamically introduce this in the recordset?